# Select com chave estrangeira Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, html-select, laravel-5.4

Olá, eu consegui resolver um problema de chave estrangeira agora a pouco e me deparei com um segundo, eu não faço ideia de como recuperar em um select na view os dados de uma outra tabela.
Se alguém puder me dar um exemplo simples, ficaria grato.
Meu create, store e edit do meu controller

```
public function create()
    {

        return view('curso.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $cursos = new Curso([
            'nome' => $request->get('nome')
        ]);

        $cursos->save();
        return redirect('/cursos');
    }

public function edit($id)
    {
        $cursos = Curso::find($id);

        return view('curso.edit', compact('cursos','id'));
    }
```

E aqui minha view create.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <h2>Cadastrar Curso</h2>
  <form method="post" action="{{action('CursoController@store')}}">

    <div class="form-row">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="lgFormGroupInput">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Nome do Curso" name="nome">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-5"></div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ action('CursoController@index') }}"> Cancelar</a>

    </div>


  </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

aqui meu edit.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <h2>Editar Curso</h2>
  <form method="post" action="{{action('CursoController@update', $id)}}">
    <div class="form-group row">
      {{csrf_field()}}
       <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
      <label for="lgFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Nome</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" value="{{$cursos->nome}}">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="lgFormGroupInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Professor</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="lgFormGroupInput" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" value="{{$cursos->professor->nome}}">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
      <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ action('CursoController@index') }}"> Cancelar</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

eu preciso mudar esse professor pra um select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa antes definir a relação no modelo, por exemplo:

```
<?php
    class Aluno extends Eloquent {
    // ...
    public function cursos(){
        return $this->hasMany('Curso');
    }
?>
```

Isto te permite acessar o modelo **Curso** de dentro de **Aluno**, é importante também realizar o contrário, isto é, dizer em Curso que que aqueles dados pertencem a aluno:

```
<?php
    class Curso extends Eloquent {
    // ...
    public function alunos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Aluno');
    }
?>
```

Os métodos do **Eloquent ORM** para isto são os *hasOne()*, *hasMany()*, *belongsTo()* e *belongsToMany()*.

Com o relacionamento configurado corretamente fica simples recuperar as informações:

```
<?php

    $jose = Aluno::where('name', '=', 'José da Silva')->first();

    foreach ($jose->cursos as $curso){
        //...
    }
?>
```

Para maiores informações, consulte a documentação do **Eloquent ORM** na página do **Laravel**.

Comment: Obrigado, Giovanni, foi de muita ajuda, agora posso recuperar os dados todos :)

Comment: E se eu quiser retornar todos os dados junto com todas as chaves estrangeiras desses dados, como fazer??